# Merge rows with the same ID in array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array like this:

```js
var testarray = [
  { "VendorID": "001", "Jan": "130", "Feb": "500" },
  { "VendorID": "001", "Jan": "0", "Feb": "0", "Mar": "1000" },
  { "VendorID": "002", "Mar": "20" } 
]

$.when(
  $.each(data, function (i, f) {
    finalarray.push({
      "VendorID": f.VendorID,
      "Jan" : f.Jan
    })
  })
).then(function() {  
})
```

This is the final array I am expecting to get:

```js
var finalarray = [
  { "VendorID": "001", "Jan": "130", "Feb": "500", "Mar": "1000" },
  { "VendorID": "002", "Jan": "0", "Feb": "0", "Mar": "20"}
]
```

I tried different ways but I am not not able to get the final result I want.

Comment: The data structure you have is an array of objects, which has nothing to do with JSON. I've edited your question to remove that confusion

Comment: When merging the property values of two objects should you take the higher value? Should they be summed? Or is there some other logic?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you. when you have multiple rows you will all the others will be 0. for example if Jan have value grater then 0 for Vendor ID 001 row 1,  then in row 2 for the same vendor ID Jan will be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var testarray = [{"VendorID" : "001", "Jan":"130","Feb":"500"},
                 {"VendorID" : "001", "Jan":"0","Feb":"0","Mar":"1000"},
                 {"VendorID" : "002", "Mar":"20"}];
var result = [];                                 
                 
// Loop array
testarray.forEach(entry => {
  // Check if we have a line with that id
  let line = result.find(resultEntry => resultEntry.VendorID === entry.VendorID);
  
  // If so, delete this line and add the merged line again
  if (line) {
    result = result.filter(resultEntry => resultEntry.VendorID !== line.VendorID);
    result.push({ ...entry, ...line })
  } else {
    // Id was not found so just push it
    result.push(entry)
  }
});

// I don't know if all months should be added but to match your expecting result, I'm going to remap the entries
result = result.map(r => { return { VendorId: r.VendorID, Jan: r.Jan || 0, Feb: r.Feb || 0, Mar: r.Mar || 0}})

// Show array
console.log(result)
```

Comment: how could i push Jan, Feb, Mar as 0 Vendor ID 002. means if not present in original array then push 0

Comment: I made an edit. Are there more field than those 3? Otherwise you could write a more generic map :)

Comment: this will do. i can manage thanks